# Using Bootstrap 4, width of Card containing 'description list' grows with list items

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to have a row containing a single card, where the card is as wide as necessary but no wider. This appears to be a job for a flex container, and I can *almost* see it working.

However, the *width* of the card increases for each element I add to the list, and shown below and also in the snippet.

Is there a way to have the card grow wide depending on the width of the text (without this strange side-effect)?

[image: Screenshot]

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Other content</h1>
    <div class="col-12 bg-danger p-1">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="p-2 bg-info">
          <div class="card border-left-primary">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">My Card</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <dl class="row">
                <dt class="col-3">Key</dt>
                <dd class="col-9">Value</dd>
                <dt class="col-3">Key</dt>
                <dd class="col-9">Value</dd>
                <!-- Add more items to see the effect  -->
              </dl>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Here we show the effect -->
    <div class="col-12 bg-danger p-1">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="p-2 bg-info">
          <div class="card border-left-primary">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">My Card</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <dl class="row">
                <dt class="col-3">Key</dt>
                <dd class="col-9">Value</dd>
                <dt class="col-3">Key</dt>
                <dd class="col-9">Value</dd>
                <dt class="col-3">Key</dt>
                <dd class="col-9">Value</dd>
                <!-- Add more items to see the effect  -->
              </dl>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### My Assumption

My guess is that the width of flexbox parent, `.row` inside the card body, was **first** calculated by their children as if the parent doesn't wrap and try to squeeze its children as tight as possible:

[image]

And then the children's width percentages were calculated based on their parent.

But again, I have no way to prove it.

#### The "Fix"

The fix would be not to solely depend on the wrapping of the rows. Instead, if one key value pair is supposed to be on their own line, explicitly define them that way using Bootstrap's row and columns as the structure:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto">
        <strong>Key</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">Value</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto">
        <strong>Key</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">Value</div>
    <!-- Add more items to see the effect  -->
</div>
```

You can use `.col-auto` to set the column width to automatic to avoid wrapping on the key and values. If you want a fixed width on the keys, set their widths instead.

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/nt6ov5fy/28/

Note: it seems like you've missed `.rows` on your `<div class="col-12 bg-danger p-1">`. I've added them back in my demo.

Comment: The problem with that approach is when they keys are different lengths you loose the description list effect, see https://jsfiddle.net/0zeroth/c4op3xhq/1/  I'll have a play with `.col-auto` and see if that helps, but so far I don't think it does.

Thanks for you detailed reply though - I'm just starting with Bootstrap so it's handy to get and idea of how to think about the ways each element effects the others.

Comment: @Zero: there are lots of things you can do in that case. It's all about what you want, as the developer. If you want the keys and values to look left aligned, regardless the length of their values, you would have to set a max width on them and then set the truncate style, like using `.text-truncate` class from Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow. It all comes down to what you want. If you can clearly define the case when the keys have different length, I can update my answer as well.

Comment: well - what i want is the definition list effect, with no line wrapping and the card as narrow as possible while handling whatever text ends up inside (it is dynamic). It looks like that isn't possible - but setting a max-width with truncating (using my original example) is a reasonable alternative.

Comment: @zero: definition list effect: the keys and values by default are displayed as block. In other words, they are on separate lines. Now in Bootstrap 3, there was an implementation of `.dl-horizontal`: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#horizontal-description, but if you look at its CSS, it had to set a max-width of 160px on the keys. I mean, the definition list key value is not displayed in a single line by default. If you want to change the default behavior to display them on a single line, you have to set a max width on the key labels.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this simply.

```
<div class="col-12 bg-danger p-1">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="p-2 bg-info">
      <div class="card border-left-primary">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">My Card</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" style="max-width: 250px !important; overflow-x: auto;">
          <dl class="row">
            <dt class="col-3">Key</dt>
            <dd class="col-9">Value</dd>
            <dt class="col-3">Key</dt>
            <dd class="col-9">Value</dd>
            <dt class="col-3">Key</dt>
            <dd class="col-9">Value</dd>
            <!-- Add more items to see the effect  -->
          </dl>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Once done, this will not let the div expand.

Comment: That doesn't work either - because the card _should_ expand if the text is wide. eg instead of "Key" / "Value" it might be "Bootstrap" / "A great library that is extremely hard to figure out when it goes wrong". 

I'm trying to stop the card getting wider when I add more items.

Comment: style="max-width: 150px !important; overflow-x: auto;"

This property will definitely work for you.

Tested this myself before suggesting..

Comment: Does not work but thanks for trying, see https://jsfiddle.net/0zeroth/97snb8zy/13/